# Sticky Broadcast Receivers - how do they work?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

Are Broadcast Receivers sticky or Intents sticky? 
From what I know- "sticky intents are those which stick around after they are broadcast. There is no such thing as sticky Broadcast Receivers; there are only receivers who can listen to sticky intents."

But how do we make intents sticky?
Is **sendStickyBroadcast(intentA)** is the only way to make intentA sticky? If yes, what would happen if I call both **sendStickyBroadcast(intentA)** and **sendBroadcast(intentA)** ? Will the intentA be available for future receivers?

I wanted to test this scenario with Logcat, but I have been receiving unexpected logs:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String CUSTOM_INTENT = "com.ashok.abacussb.my_intent";
    Button button;
    Receiver1 receiver1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sendBroadcast(new Intent(CUSTOM_INTENT));
        Log.d("abd", "after sendBroadcast() "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());

        receiver1 = new Receiver1();

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("abd", "inside onClick()");
                Intent intent = registerReceiver(receiver1, new IntentFilter(CUSTOM_INTENT));
                Log.d("abd", (intent == null ? "null": ""+intent));
            }
        });
    }
}

public class Receiver1 extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("abd", "inside Receiver1 onReceive() "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}
```

and the LOGS:

```
09-21 16:26:43.845: D/abd(26620): after sendBroadcast() main
09-21 16:26:49.665: D/abd(26620): inside onClick()
09-21 16:26:49.685: D/abd(26620): Intent { act=com.ashok.abacussb.my_intent flg=0x10 }
09-21 16:26:49.770: D/abd(26620): inside Receiver1 onReceive() main
```

Receiver1 is registered on button click, which is clearly after **sendBroadcast()** is executed. Why is the **onReceive()** method executed & the intent returned by **registerReceiver()** not NULL, since it was not a **sendStickyBroadcast()** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are Broadcast Receivers sticky or Intents sticky?

Broadcast `Intent`s sent via `sendStickyBroadcast()` are sticky, if you hold the proper permission to send such broadcasts.

> Is sendStickyBroadcast(intentA) is the only way to make intentA sticky?

Yes.

> If yes, what would happen if I call both sendStickyBroadcast(intentA) and sendBroadcast(intentA) ? Will the intentA be available for future receivers?

AFAIK, the behavior is undocumented. I would not recommend using that pattern.

> Why is the onReceive() method executed & the intent returned by registerReceiver() not NULL, since it was not a sendStickyBroadcast() ?

Perhaps you previously sent a sticky broadcast for that same action string. Reboot your device or emulator and try your test again.